# PWA - React on Root path and Sub path

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I created PWA App with CRA.
I have deployed it on root path let's say https://www.example.com/

I have another PWA app using same CRA and it's deployed on https://www.example.com/cms/

So due to workers paths and pages are now cached. So each time I try to visit https://www.example.com/cms/ it always redirects to https://www.example.com/ and user don't have access to Apps deployed on Subpath.

Comment: A possible solution could be to use subdomains, like `example.com` for your first PWA and then `cms.example.com` for the other application. On your server those files still could reside as is.

Comment: @r3dst0rm I came across that but due to some policies, i am unable to implement subdomain concept.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Maybe you can achieve what you want by selectively add what you want to cache: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#storing_resources

Comment: @r3dst0rm can you tell me what exactly should I remove to solve this issue.